# How to convert bash script to powershell my code is here

Tags: powershell

I want to convert my bash script into powershell, my script is here

```
sed -i "s/DS_PROP_KEYS :=.*/$DATASOURCE_KEY/OMS_Add_Tenant_Util.sql;"
```

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far and where, specifically, you're stuck.

Comment: Your `sed` command is broken; please start with a working `sed` command - ideally, provide a  [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There are implementations of `sed` for Windows; you might want to download and use one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without writing a function this is the closest I've seen to replicating sed functionality:

```
(Get-Content file.txt) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "^SourceRegexp$", "DestinationString"} | Set-Content file.txt
```

Comment: @DivyaSaikhede Glad I could help, if you're happy with my answer you can [Mark it as Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).